# Maven dependencies with jenkins using incremental builds

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a multimodule project, with one of the sub-modules depending on another as this:

```
pom.xml (parent pom)
|
+---- pom.xml (project A)
|
+---- pom.xml (project B) depends on A
```

I'm building it in jenkins, using the option "Incremental builds" (Maven job type). My problem is that **when only project B has changes** (that implies that jenkins is building **ONLY** project B), Jenkins is downloading latest snapshot from project A, instead of using binaries present in "target" directory of project A (generated in a previous build).

If full build is triggered, the problem goes away, and Jenkins uses correct binaries.
Has anyone have the same problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

its not a problem, its the way maven operates. artifacts are *always* brought from the repository, even for multi-module builds. if you build the whole tree you just dont notice because the artifacts pulled from the local repo are the ones your build put there just a few minutes ago.

you'll get the exact same behaviour if you opened a command prompt to project B's root dir and executed a maven build from the command line - maven would look for A in the local repository (and the remotes, if not found) and wont look in A's /target directory.

if this was standard maven you could use maven's [also-make flag](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) from the root directory and tell maven to build project B and all of B's dependencies, which would make maven also build A.